# Busca automática (Auto complete search)

Tags: java, ajax, hibernate, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Boa tarde!
Estou tentando implementar um auto complete search no meu sistema. Mas até agora não consegui um resultado satisfatório. O que eu quero é quando o usuário pesquisar vá mostrando o resultado, como o google faz. Já pesquisei pra caramba, já tentei implementar, mas não consegui fazer de um jeito satisfatório nem achei material/tutoriais.

Alguém pode me mostrar o caminho para fazer isso utilizando Spring Boot+Ajax+Thymeleaf+Bootstrap?

Comment: Tem tantos compoentes: https://www.devbridge.com/sourcery/components/jquery-autocomplete/
https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: @dhb Obrigado! Vou tentar implementar no meu projeto.

Comment: Oi, encontrei esse exemplo disponível no github: https://github.com/lowrin/spring-boot-input-autocomplete-example

Comment: Consegui implementar e colocar para funcionar. Ainda não está perfeito mas está funcionando. Eu uso Spring Boot, Thymeleaf, Jquery. Dá uma olhada nas classes ProjectController.java, ProjectSuggestion.java, ProjectSuggestionWrapper.java e na tela src/main/resources/templates/us/add.html. O meu projeto está aqui: https://github.com/labens-ufrn/apf-bsi.